# Problems activating Windows 10 Pro on new digital licensed computers when using an imaged HDD containing same OS version

Tags: windows-10, disk-image, windows-activation, licensing

I'm having trouble with activating Windows 10 Pro on computers that come with an OEM digital license for Windows 10 Pro. Here's some background..

I have a company that performs video surveillance services. We have hundreds of computers that are used to record locally and upload the video footage to the cloud. Due to the volume of computers that we use, I cannot set up each computer one-by-one. Instead, I create a HDD image with Windows 10 and all our software/configuration already installed. It is a lot of work to setup a computer and create the initial image, but after creating it I simply buy the computers and burn the image on the drive, change the boot settings to boot from the new drive. After that, the computer comes up and running for its intended purpose. The computers I purchase have Windows 10 pre-installed on the internal SD card. So far, all has been working well as I just described. I have imaged and setup hundreds of computers and they come up and automatically activate with Microsoft, since the version of windows is the same on the digital license as it is on the HDD image.

The problem started when the computer that I purchase was re-branded (as brand-B) and the old brand (brand-A) is no longer available. The hardware of the two brands is identical and the HDD image boots and works well on the new brand of computer. The only problem is that the digital license doesn't activate automatically. When I boot one of the brand-B computers with the HDD image, and then if I check the Windows 10 license activation, I get the following message:

"We can't reach a critical Windows service. Make sure you're connected to the Internet, wait a few minutes, and try again. Error code: 0x80070426"

To be clear, I am connected to the Internet and the activation never occurs, even after waiting significant amount of time. I am not trying to do anything illegal, just need to be able to activate the computer automatically, using the digital license that is part of the OEM product. If that means to make a slight change to the HDD image, I am OK with that, as I can create a new (modified) version of the image. I just don't want to start over and build a new HDD image from scratch. Any ideas about how this works with activating with a digital license and what it will take to build this change into my HDD image?

BTW, I am unable to get any support from Microsoft about this. It seems that they don't support customers these days, and expect that these types of issues shall be handled by external support groups like this one. If anyone has suggestions of how I can get Microsoft to help, that information would be helpful too. I'm willing to pay for support.

Comment: The problem started when the computer that I purchase was re-branded (as brand-B) and the old brand (brand-A) is no longer available. .... Driver problem perhaps?

Comment: I don't think so, because the newly branded computer boots and works perfectly to perform the operations for which it is used. In fact, several of these computers have been working out in the field with no issues for several weeks/months. The only thing it doesn't do is automatically activate windows-10 Pro (using the digital license).

Comment: "Drivers" includes BIOS (UEFI) and that is likely different.

Comment: But the newly branded computer boots from my HDD image and runs perfectly. There are no functional problems with the new computer as far as I know. I would think a incompatible BIOS or any H/W driver incompatibility issue wouldn't allow me to get this far. Am I just naive about that? I think the problem must have to do with Microsoft accepting the digital license. I'm not sure how the process of the computer "calling in" to MS and MS verifying the digital license is handled. All I know is that with the new brand computer, the digital license is no longer activating.

Comment: Perhaps call Microsoft Licensing Support.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, John. I just added a comment to the original problem statement about MS support (or lack thereof).

Comment: @user19208349 - You should be able to activate the install over the phone.  If that works you know it's a problem with your base image.  Are you sure these devices came with the same edition of Windows?  Activating by phone is a free service by the way.  Based on my 2 decades of experience, it's either the image itself, or a required service hasn't been started.  I would need more information to fully diagnose the issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain that it is the same edition of Windows (Windows 10 Pro). Thanks for the suggestion to activate over the phone. I will give it a try.

Comment: BTW, after reading some articles, I get the idea that the way the digital license works is there is a token from each computer product manufacturer that is associated with the user's Microsoft account and when you setup Windows, it stores the token (associated with your user account) somewhere on the cloud. If this is the case, it would explain why the newly branded computers don't work and the old ones do. I'm going to try to setup a newly branded computer from scratch and activate it on my MS account. Then I'll try using the HDD image again on one that isn't activating and see if that helps.